# Question About Irreductibility of an element in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

I $A$ is a principal ideal domain  and let N  the set of non zero elements, that do not have an inverse and that cannot be decomposed in a product of irreductibles.

If $a \in N$

Let's create the set $I = aA$

I am trying to understand why a is not irreductible

(This is part of the proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetics our professor gave us)

**Is it just that if $a$ was irreductible then $a = a$ so it can be decomposed in a product of irreductibles?**

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If $a$ cannot be decomposed into a product of irreducible elements, then $a$ can be both, irreducible and reducible. In a noetherian ring every element can be decomposed into irreducible elements.

Comment: Let me change the question

Comment: Principal ideal domains are factorial

Comment: @menag that's precisely what i'm trying to understand thanks though

Comment: @aribaldi What is the relevance of $I$ in your question? Is it part of your attempt at a solution. If so, how did you plan to use $I$?

Comment: yes It's part of the proof if the fundamental theorem of arithmetics that our professor gave us

Comment: I think I might have understood, is it right though?

Answer (score 0):

if A  a factorial domain , for $a\in A$, a not 0 and not invertible, we have equivalence :

a irreductible

a prime

aA irreductible ideal

aA maximal ideal in the set of principal ideal and propre

aA prime ideal

Comment: But I'm asking about the element a that cannot be decomposed in a product of irreductibles, why is that very element not irreductible?

Comment: I tried to translate your question but I do not understand the problem.

Comment: is that N is the subset of A containing all the irreducible elements of A?

Comment: from the comments, i understant that  you want to show a principal ring is factrial,  is  not it?

Comment: i want to know why an element that cannot be decomposed into irreductibles cannot be an irreductible

Comment: But not in a factrial domain

Comment: in a principal ideal domain

Comment: a principal ideal domain is a factorial domain,

Comment: dude you're not helping me

Comment: ok, I'm not greedy of knowledge, I really like to help you mate but you have to face me understand the issue

Comment: iwe have a irreductible is equivalent to say if a=bc thene b or c is a unite.

Comment: @ayadi_mohammed sorry that was unnecessary